# PHP/HTML if option is selected -> define variable

Tags: php, jquery, html

I want to define a variable (`$_SESSION['name']`) when a option is selected (without posting) When select a option, it should define the the variable without posting or refreshing the page. For example something like this, maybe with jQuery or something. Can someone help me out?

```
   <select name="location">
        <option <?php $_SESSION['name'] = "US";?>>US</option>
        <option <?php $_SESSION['name'] = "GB";?>>GB</option>
        <option <?php $_SESSION['name'] = "DE";?>>DE</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: I have to setup a post for this, this isn´t possible because of the usage of my dynamic system. I need a function that defines a variable when a option is selected without posting.

Comment: You can only do it through ajax then. jQuery .ajax has lots of goodies to use: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: I am going to start typing an answer but I suspect it will be marked as duplicate and closed before I am done.

Comment: Go for it! TIME IS TICKING ... CHOP CHOP!

Comment: @IncredibleHat  es nada

Answer (score 2):

ok, do this:

```
<select name="location" onChange="thingChanged(this)">
    <option value="US">US</option>
    <option value="GB">GB</option>
    <option value="DE">DE</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function thingChanged(thing){
        $.post('pageMarkingSessionVar.php',{
                sel:$(thing).val();
               });
    }
</script>
```

then on pageMarkingSessionVar.php do:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  if(isset($_POST["sel"])){
    $_SESSION["name"] = $_POST["sel"];
  }
?>
```

quick and dirty but you get the idea.

**edit:**  oh yeh, make sure jQuery is loaded

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about what you want exactly, but maybe it can help:

```js
var freq = 1000;

function getLocation(){
  var location = document.getElementsByName("location").value
  var ajax_req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if(ajax_req.readyState==0 || ajax_req.readyState==4){
    ajax_req.open('POST','yourwebsite.io',true);
    ajax_req.onload=handleResponse;
    ajax_req.send("loc="+location);
   }
   setTimeout('getLocation()', freq);
}

function handleResponse(){
  //Handle response
}

getLocation();
```

```html
   <select name="location">
        <option value="US">US</option>
        <option value="GB">GB</option>
        <option value="DE">DE</option>
    </select>
```

This is HTML/JS, you just have to do `$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['loc']` in *yourwebsite.io*'s php file. Make sure you've enabled session by adding `session_start();` before **ANY** HTML code (more info [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)).

Comment: I upvoted you for your efforts because `1-reppers` never do...

Comment: Thank's a lot ! ;)